# Supported bindings for WCF streaming transfers

Tags: wcf, streaming, wcf-binding

I was using basicHttpBinding for streaming transfer, When I change binding to netTcpBinding , Service start to throw exception... Please help me to understand the fastest binding to transfer streams... 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some good links for file transferring, might help you get to the bottom of what's going on:

- Streaming: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx)

> ...you can use only transport-level security options for streaming and you cannot turn on reliable sessions. Streaming is only available with the following system-defined bindings:
>
> - BasicHttpBinding
> - NetTcpBinding
> - NetNamedPipeBinding
> - WebHttpBinding

- Transferring Chunks: [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCF_FileTransfer_Progress.aspx) (may not be relevant)
- Streaming Issues: [weblogs.asp.net](http://weblogs.asp.net/jclarknet/archive/2008/02/14/wcf-streaming-issue-under-iis.aspx)

Comment: answer in MSDN link,
Because of these functional constraints, you can use only transport-level security options for streaming and you cannot turn on reliable sessions. As a result, streaming is only available with the following system-defined bindings:

BasicHttpBinding
NetTcpBinding
NetNamedPipeBinding

Comment: @ArsenMkrtchyan Thanks for taking the time, that should've been in the answer

Comment: @Basic have added that to the answer for visibility.