# Uploading file with WCF streaming, tiny reads from stream

Tags: wcf, streaming, size, buffer

I've implemented file uploading using WCF's streaming. Everything works as expected, however i faced one issue: i'm allocating 4kb buffer to read from incoming stream, but WCF reads only 255 bytes. Here is my upload function:

```
public UploadResponse UploadFile(FileDto fileDto)
        {
            using (var inStream = fileDto.FileStream)
            using (var outStream = new FileStream("OutFile.txt", FileMode.Create))
            {
                var buffer = new byte[4096];
                int count;
                while ((count = inStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    outStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
            }
            return new UploadResponse {DocumentId = -1};
        }
```

Only 255 bytes reading at this line: while ((count = inStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0). Is there any setting i can change, or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: could you post your wcf configuration

Comment: and your service contract, too, please - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Post your configs if you can please. The config should specify the defaults or overriden values, something like below:

```
    <binding name="FileTransferServicesBinding"
    maxReceivedMessageSize="1048576" messageEncoding="Mtom">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="1048576" maxBytesPerRead="1048576"
    maxNameTableCharCount="1048576" maxStringContentLength="1048576"> </readerQuotas>
    </binding>
```

Try this [MSDN Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/7b9e9cd9-49f1-498c-85c5-fc869dddae87) the guy mentions that he had the same issue with only getting 255 bytes, he has an answer marked and it seems to resolve his issue. It states:

*"In order to pass a stream to a WCF method, the Stream parameter must be the only parameter in the operation (or in the message body)..."*

Comment: I did not tried readerQuotas. Thanks for the sample. I'll try it and get back with results.

Comment: The default value for maxBytesPerRead is 4096 though, so I'm not so sure that's going to be the problem.

Comment: Check the links in my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898168/supported-bindings-for-wcf-streaming-transfers/911371#911371

Comment: I tried to set maxBytesPerRead and other quotas to higher values, but without success. Still WCF reads only 255 bytes from incoming stream. I found this link http://forums.asp.net/p/1359234/2803427.aspx. Seems like same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you had the same problem I did. I solved it here: [File download through WCF slower than through IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451376/file-download-through-wcf-slower-than-through-iis)